# Array of struct not updating outside the closure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of struct called displayStruct

```
struct displayStruct{
let price : String!
let Description : String!
}
```

I am reading data from firebase and add it to my array of struct called myPost which is initialize below

```
var myPost:[displayStruct] = []
```

I made a function to add the data from the database to my array of struct like this

```
 func addDataToPostArray(){
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("Post").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:  {
        snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let price = snapshotValue?["price"] as! String
        let description = snapshotValue?["Description"] as! String
        // print(description)
        //  print(price)

        let postArr =  displayStruct(price: price, Description: description)
        self.myPost.append(postArr)
   //if i print self.myPost.count i get the correct length

    })
}
```

within this closure if I print myPost.count i get the correct length but outside this function if i print the length i get zero even thou i declare the array globally(I think)

I called this method inside viewDidLoad method

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   // setup after loading the view.

    super.viewDidLoad()
   addDataToPostArray()
    print(myPeople.count) --> returns 0 for some reason


  }
```

I want to use that length is my method below a fucntion of tableView

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return myPost.count --> returns 0
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase `observe` call to the database is `asynchronous` which means when you are requesting for the value it might not be available as it might be in process of fetching it.

That's why your both of the queries to `count` returns 0 in `viewDidLoad` and `DataSource delegeate` method.

```
  databaseRef.child("Post").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:  { // inside closure }
```

Inside the closure, the code has been already executed and so you have the values.

What you need to do is you need to reload your `Datasource` in main thread inside the closure.

```
   databaseRef.child("Post").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:  { 
       // After adding to array
       DispatchQueue.main.asyc {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       } 

    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering! But i get an error saying the module "Dispatch" has no member named main

Comment: @packability It is `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`

Comment: @Sorry typo mistake. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You making a asynchronous network request inside closure and compiler doesn't wait for the response, so just Reload Table when get post data. replace the code with below it work works fine for you. All the best.

```
 func addDataToPostArray(){
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Post").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:  {
            snapshot in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let price = snapshotValue?["price"] as! String
            let description = snapshotValue?["Description"] as! String
            // print(description)
            //  print(price)

            let postArr =  displayStruct(price: price, Description: description)
            self.myPost.append(postArr)
            print(self.myPost.count)
            print(self.myPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
       //if i print self.myPost.count i get the correct length

        })
    }
```

Comment: After i called the reload data method , it solved my problem

Comment: That's great. Keep uestioning. (raise answer to accept, so next time another people can directly solve the problem.)@packability

Comment: Just click on up arrow where i answered if you think you solved your problem. @packability